# How to install multiple versions of php on one server?

Tags: php, linux, centos

I want to install two PHP versions on a single server .
I have PHP v7.1 installed on my server and i want to install another version that is php5.5 on my server.

I tried installing v5.5 but it either upgrades from the previous version or it does not get installed because of the previous version .

What commands should i use to install an additional phpv5.5 (having phpv7.1 already installed) on my server.

I'm using centos 6.8

Comment: Why don't you just run docker container with specified php version

Comment: i dont know how to .

Comment: any other easy option ????